# Path in Line Chart is too small

Tags: javascript, d3.js, graph, linegraph

I am currently working with d3.js to create a line graph and facing a problem with the correct width and height of the path.

```js
const margin = {
  top: 50,
  right: 50,
  bottom: 50,
  left: 50
}
const width = 700
const height = 500
const dateConv = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d")

const svg = d3.select("#temparatureGraph").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform",
    "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")

d3.xml("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ForceSergeant/D3LineGraph/6aa5b375dbc0bd2ca86f6fcef73369caae64232e/data.xml")
  .then((xml) => {

    let values = []
    let dates = []
    let times = []

    //Processign the data
    const document = d3.select(xml.documentElement)
    const temperature = document.selectAll('temperature')
    temperature.selectAll("average").each(function() {
      values.push(+this.textContent)
    })
    const date = document.selectAll('utc')
    date.selectAll("date").each(function() {
      dates.push(dateConv(this.textContent))
    })
    const time = document.selectAll('utc')
    time.selectAll("time").each(function() {
      times.push(this.textContent)
    })

    console.log(dates)
    console.log(times)

    dates = dates.map((value, index) => {
      value.setHours(times[index].split(":")[0])
      return value
    })

    const data = []
    for (var i = 0; i < dates.length; i++) {
      data.push({
        date: dates[i],
        value: values[i]
      })
    }

    console.log(data)


    const xScale = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width])
    const yScale = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0])

    xScale.domain(d3.extent(data, d => d.date))
    yScale.domain([d3.min(data, d => d.value), d3.max(data, d => d.value)])

    const xaxis = d3.axisBottom()
      .ticks(d3.timeMonth.every(1))
      .tickFormat(d3.timeFormat('%b %y'))
      .scale(xScale);
    const yaxis = d3.axisLeft().scale(yScale);

    //x-Achse
    svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xaxis);

    //y-Achse
    svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis")
      .call(yaxis)
      .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("dy", ".75em")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Grad Celsius");

    const line = d3.line()
      .x(function(d) {
        return xScale(d.date);
      })
      .y(function(d) {
        return yScale(d.value);
      });

    svg.append("path")
      .datum(data)
      .attr("class", "dataPath")
      .attr("d", line)
  })
```

```css
.axis line {
    stroke: red;
}

/* axis contour */
.axis path {
    stroke: green;
}

/* axis text */
.axis text {
    fill: blue;
}

.dataPath {
    fill: none;
    stroke: gold;
    stroke-miterlimit: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="temparatureGraph"></div>
```

- Values is an array of temperature for every Day and Hour
- Dates is an array with the corresponding Date
- Times is an array the corresponding Time
  Data is an array of obj with following form: [{date: , value: }]

Everything is working fine but the path is too small and does not fit the x-Axis as you can see in the image.

Her is the [XML-file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ForceSergeant/D3LineGraph/6aa5b375dbc0bd2ca86f6fcef73369caae64232e/data.xml).

[image: Graph]
[image: Arrays]

Thanks for every help.

Comment: Can you turn your code into a runnable example? Make your XML available at some URL through github, for example, and use a runnable snippet or JSFiddle to make it work on site. It will help you get better answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some missing data in your example, specifically, at January 31rst 2018, `value` is NaN.

[image]

In d3, you need to set which values a line chart can skip, otherwise it tries to draw them, breaks, and (unhelpfully) exits without warning. You can do this using [`d3.line().defined()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-shape/#line_defined), which I did in the below (zoomed in) example. Notice how the line stops existing and re-starts again later.

```js
const margin = {
  top: 50,
  right: 50,
  bottom: 50,
  left: 50
}
const width = 700
const height = 500
const dateConv = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d")

const svg = d3.select("#temparatureGraph").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform",
    "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")

d3.xml("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ForceSergeant/D3LineGraph/6aa5b375dbc0bd2ca86f6fcef73369caae64232e/data.xml")
  .then((xml) => {

    let values = []
    let dates = []
    let times = []

    //Processign the data
    const document = d3.select(xml.documentElement)
    const temperature = document.selectAll('temperature')
    temperature.selectAll("average").each(function() {
      values.push(+this.textContent)
    })
    const date = document.selectAll('utc')
    date.selectAll("date").each(function() {
      dates.push(dateConv(this.textContent))
    })
    const time = document.selectAll('utc')
    time.selectAll("time").each(function() {
      times.push(this.textContent)
    })

    dates.forEach((value, index) => {
      value.setHours(times[index].split(":")[0])
    })

    const data = []
    // I just added this for simplicity,
    // it's unrelated to the solution
    for (var i = 700; i < 750; i++) {
      data.push({
        date: dates[i],
        value: values[i]
      })
    }

    const xScale = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width])
    const yScale = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0])

    xScale.domain(d3.extent(data, d => d.date))
    yScale.domain([d3.min(data, d => d.value), d3.max(data, d => d.value)]);

    const xaxis = d3.axisBottom()
      .ticks(d3.timeMonth.every(1))
      .tickFormat(d3.timeFormat('%b %y'))
      .scale(xScale);
    const yaxis = d3.axisLeft().scale(yScale);

    //x-Achse
    svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xaxis);

    //y-Achse
    svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis")
      .call(yaxis)
      .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("dy", ".75em")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Grad Celsius");

    const line = d3.line()
      .defined(function(d) { return !isNaN(d.value); })
      .x(function(d) {
        return xScale(d.date);
      })
      .y(function(d) {
        return yScale(d.value);
      });

    svg.append("path")
      .datum(data)
      .attr("class", "dataPath")
      .attr("d", line)
  })
```

```css
.axis line {
    stroke: red;
}

/* axis contour */
.axis path {
    stroke: green;
}

/* axis text */
.axis text {
    fill: blue;
}

.dataPath {
    fill: none;
    stroke: gold;
    stroke-miterlimit: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="temparatureGraph"></div>
```